# Sitecore 500 Error Logging / Alerts

Tags: c#, logging, sitecore

#### Problem

Currently, I'm looking to serve a custom 500 error page as well as log and alert a web master about the condition that was hit (What URL, stack trace, timestamp, etc.).

I tried defined custom http errors under system configuration, but the error pages were not hit.
I am able to handle 404s and their related errors (layoutnotfound).

#### Question

Should I intercept the context in global.asax to handle the 500 errors and return a custom page? Is there another way with Sitecore to achieve what I'm looking for?

Mainly, I'm looking for best practice of logging / alerts for 500 errors with Sitecore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

[Here](http://www.markvanaalst.com/sitecore/using-elmah-for-error-logging-within-sitecore/) is an article on using it with Sitecore.

Comment: I looked into this. Was wondering if there was a way to do this without having to worry about their code. 

Simply writing to a log file / emailing alerts to related developers

Comment: What do you mean "worry about their code"?  It's basically a drop in solution, with some web.config additions.  Super easy.

Comment: Namely a superior on the project didn't like the idea and that was his response. Just trying to come up with a solution that will be approved.  Talked over it with him and swayed his opinion on the issue. We're trying Elmah.

Comment: Ended up using this to provide more in-depth email reporting and allowing access to RSS feeds for those who want to keep an eye on errors but not have them crowing their email.

Thanks for the suggestion. =]

Answer (score 5):

Elmah is great and does a good job. You can also use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) to log exceptions. All you do is add an application_error method in global.asax and you can track all the errors that occur. You can also add different appenders and can log messages in a log file, database and email them.

Here is the code that logs the error and includes some additional information like url and Current sitecore item:

```
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global));
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Exception error = Context.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
                log.Fatal(
                    GetErrorMessage(), error);
            }
        }
        private string GetErrorMessage()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Application_Error: Unhandled exception has been occured.");
            try
            {
                sb.AppendLine("Current Request: " + Context.Request.RawUrl);
                Sitecore.Data.Items.Item currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
                if (currentItem != null)
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Current Item ({0}): {1}", currentItem.ID, currentItem.Paths.FullPath));
                if (Sitecore.Context.Database != null)
                    sb.AppendLine("Current Database: " + Sitecore.Context.Database.Name);
            }
            catch { } // in no way should we prevent the site from logging the error
            return sb.ToString();

        }
```

If you want an easy solution I would recommend going with Elmah. If you want to have more control and more logging options you should go with a custom log4net solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried defined custom http errors
>   under system configuration, but the
>   error pages were not hit. I am able to
>   handle 404s and their related errors
>   (layoutnotfound).

On that particular point...Be aware that custom errors behave differently when accessed locally. Also, by default you need to use physical files (not sitecore pages) for these pages. You need be aware of IIS behaviour when returning status codes over 200 and how it is dependant on the  configuration within web.config and (if running in integrated mode) the  section. In particular, see the flow chart half way down the first link below.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/267/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis-70/
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689487(v=VS.90).aspx

You might also want to change the RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect setting to "true" to provide better http responses without redirects.